# Static bytecode analysis tool that detects methods returning null?

Tags: java, null, bytecode, static-analysis

I need to detect programmatically, if a given method may or may not return null.

The [checker framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/) seems to be able to do this, but only on annotated source code. I need it on byte code. Specifically, I need to verify claims like:

```
Method x.y.Z#foo() cannot return null.
```

where I have only the bytecode of class x.y.Z.

Do you know of any tool that'd support that?

Is this even possible in the general case? As far as I can see, it is not equivalent to the halting problem, since one does not need to figure out the exact path through the program. For example in

```
Foo bar() {
    if (cond) { return null; } else { return new Foo(); }
}
```

the analysis tool needs not care about `cond`, it is enough to note that in at least one of all possible paths, `null` is returned, so the claim that bar cannot return null could be rejected.

Note: I would accept false positives, for example, `cond` could be just `false` and the analysis tool could still claim that bar() could return null (which is equivalent to saying that we cannot proove in the general case that `cond` must be true).

Comment: It'd be impossible to determine if *all* methods *might* return null without running it through all possible code paths.

Comment: In the general case, this is equivalent to the halting problem.  For one thing, before you can find out whether it can return `null`, you must find out whether it will return at all.

Comment: @SLaks I don't think so, as explained above. I just need to establish that there is at least 1 path that leads to `return null`. It is ok to have false positives like in `if (false) return null;` I will edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: @DaveNewton True. But observe that the question "is x one of the possible results" (the one that interests me) is very different from "is the result x". In other words, to determine whther `if (cond) A; else B` can return null, is the same as determining if A can return null **or** B can return null.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any tools that do this, but if false positives are acceptable, then I think this is possible.

The value returned from a method will be ultimately be sourced from one of

- A constant within the method
- A provided parameter
- A field
- The result of another java method call
- The result of a native call
- A constructor call
- A source I've forgotten about

If you assume that any field or parameter might be null, and that any native call might return null then each method can be marked as possibly returning null if

- The flow of the method can return a null constant
- The flow of the method can return a field
- The flow of the method can return a parameter value
- The flow of the method can return the result of a native call
- The flow of the method can return a value from a method that can itself return null

However, it probably isn't useful as it is likely to produce a high proportion of false positives (you must have some maximum percentage that is acceptable, otherwise you could meet your requirement with a method that simply returned true).

You might be able to add additional heuristics to reduce the number of fields/parameters/methods that are considered to be null.

The ASM tree api provides all the building blocks you'd need to try and implement this, including flow analysis.

Comment: It's going to get a bit more complicated. I really would want to avoid the false positives due to fields and parameter values. For the latter, I know whether they can be null or not.

Comment: You might be able to use the edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull annotation (or one of the other ones) to reduce the scope of the problem. I forget what guarantees the findbugs analysis provides for these, but if you assume that your codebase has 0 findbugs warnings for these, your tool could trust that annotated fields are non null.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come to mind:

- Use findbugs. The bug patterns starting with NP check for that, e.g.:

  - NP_LOAD_OF_KNOWN_NULL_VALUE
  - NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE
  - NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_MIGHT_BE_INFEASIBLE

Alternatively you can build your [own bug pattern](http://code.google.com/p/findbugs-tutorials/) checking for that...

- Use the build in eclipse checkers. If you go to Preferences\Java\Compiler\Errors/Warnings there is a whole section (Null analysis) dedicated to that. You are able to change those settings to warning or error...

**[Update]**

If you want to do it programmatically you can do it (like findbugs) and use a byte code library to do that:

- [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) with a DOM-like API
- [ASM](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm/) with a SAX-like API. Tutorials, user guides and reference documents available [here](http://www.ow2.org/)

From what i have read and heard ASM seems to be a [good choice](http://asm.ow2.org/current/asm-eng.pdf). And if I remember correctly findbugs also switched to ASM (however still have some bcel inside?). To not start from scratch you may use findbugs with your/their detectors and use it as a library. So you call their bug detecting function and start it programmatically and then analyze the return values. I would ask at the findbugs mailing list for further details.

**[Update2]**
This [guy](https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2013-August/003859.html) may be doing exactly what you need - so you should contact him...

Comment: Findbugs is great, but I need to do it programmatically.